# webAudio : connecting audio with a low pass filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, filter

Im new to this whole coding stuff and im working on an interactive online music video with the option to mix and edit the audio through a use of filters.
Im stuck trying to connect a Low Pass Filter.
With the help of Boris at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

I have managed to get this code down:

```
var FilterSample = {
    FREQ_MUL: 7000,
    QUAL_MUL: 30,
    playing: false
};

FilterSample.play = function () {

    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = BUFFERS.techno;

    var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
    filter.type = 0; // LOW PASS
    filter.frequency.value = 5000;

    source.connect(filter);
    filter.connect(context.destination);

    if (!source.start) source.start = source.noteOn;
    source.start(0);
    source.loop = true;

    this.source = source;
    this.filter = filter;
};

FilterSample.stop = function () {
    if (!this.source.stop) this.source.stop = source.noteOff;
    this.source.stop(0);
    this.source.noteOff(0);
};

FilterSample.toggle = function () {
    this.playing ? this.stop() : this.play();
    this.playing = !this.playing;
};

FilterSample.changeFrequency = function (element) {
    var minValue = 40;
    var maxValue = context.sampleRate / 2;

    var numberOfOctaves = Math.log(maxValue / minValue) / Math.LN2;
    var multiplier = Math.pow(2, numberOfOctaves * (element.value - 1.0));

    this.filter.frequency.value = maxValue * multiplier;
};

FilterSample.changeQuality = function (element) {
    this.filter.Q.value = element.value * this.QUAL_MUL;
};

FilterSample.toggleFilter = function (element) {
    this.source.disconnect(0);
    this.filter.disconnect(0);
    if (element.checked) {
        this.source.connect(this.filter);
        this.filter.connect(context.destination);
    } else {
        this.source.connect(context.destination);
    }
};
```

My problem starts at the beginning, I want to connect my own audio file to the FilterSample function I believe.

I have created a play/pause button which runs the FilterSample.toggle() onClick and 2 range sliders but I can't make it play my own audio.

Comment: Did you succeed to play a sound with no low-pass filter ?

Comment: I haven't no, i know how to put in audio tags and play a sound if I want to but I need to run through all the script code I've written

Comment: What i mean is : first step is to have a sound playing. After, you'll add a filter.

Comment: Ok, so in the <body> tag i'll code some music to play on autoplay. Take the toggle (play/pause) button out of the dilemma. What would i then need to code to run it through the filter?

Comment: I have a <div> tag now with audio tags within it playing music. one stage down! :)

Comment: The real first step here is to have a mp3 playing using webAudio, not the Audio tag.

Comment: this is something i haven't done before, but if you believe this is the best way I will look into it. Thanks!